# what event is called up when user touch canvas's blank space in windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7

When user touch a canvas in the blank space, 
where there are no any controllers there,
 what event is called up?

Comment: You can have an event fire for whatever you want. Tap, MouseLeftButtonDown, MouseLeftButtonUp etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can capture events on any UI element, as long as their background is not set to transparent. When you create a new page, you can handle touches on the root `Grid` element as follows:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" MouseLeftButtonDown="LayoutRoot_MouseLeftButtonDown">
</Grid>
```

Visual Studio will automatically add the code-behind for the `LayoutRoot_MouseLeftButtonDown` event handler.